# Unable to run an application on a real devise from Tizen IDE - my devise isn't detected

Tags: tizen

I have Eclipse for Tizen 2.4 installed and all other stuff. When I connect my Tizen Samsung to my computer, I can see it in Explorer so the OS detects it. However, in the IDE I don't see it in Connection Explorer at all and thus cannot run an application on my real devise from the IDE. I wonder, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug or connect your phone to Tizen SDK, you need to have Developer optionenabled in your target/phone.

Steps to Enable developer option:

1. Open Phone Dialer by clicking the Green Dial icon
2. Type *#84936#
3. Toggle the button present next to Developer Option
4. Developer option is now visible in Settings
5. Open App tray and select Settings
6. Scroll to the bottom and select Developer Options
7. Toggle the button present next to USB Debugging

On performing the last step(7), USB debugging would be enabled on your device and you can use it with Tizen SDK.

Comment: The code 84936 corresponds to TIZEN. If you see the dialer, the digits will correspond to alphabets in the word TIZEN. If above ans worked for u, plz mark it as ans, so that if someone else faces similar issues, then it will be helpful.

Comment: I mean, how do you know this code will make a device activate developer mode?